# Adding more items to FirebaseRecyclerAdapter?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I want to implement endless scrolling with FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.
But I don't know how to add more items to my FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.

My adapter initialization code:

```
mAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<RowStorage, MusicItemHolder>(RowStorage.class,
                R.layout.music_list_element, MusicItemHolder.class, databaseMusicReference) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(MusicItemHolder musicHolder,
                                              RowStorage model, int position) {
                musicHolder.setMusicTitle(model.getTitle());
                musicHolder.setArtistName(model.getArtist());
                musicHolder.setMusicIcon(model.getIcon());
            }
};
mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

And my onScrollListener code:

```
mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener(mLayoutManager) {
            @Override
            public void onLoadMore(int page, int totalItemsCount) {
                // how can I add (not overwrite) more items here?
            }
});
```

Is there any any way to add items to existing FirebaseRecyclerAdapter?

**Update**

Is there any way to return from functions startAt() and endAt() sorted by key range of values?
For example:

I have this database:

```
"globalNode" : {
   "node1" : {
      some values
   }
   "node2" : {
      some values
   }
   "node3" : {
      some values
   }
   "node4" : {
      some values
   }
}
```

And I want to retrieve at first 1 2 nodes and then 3 and 4 nodes onScroll. How can I do this with functions startAt() and endAt() if nodes in database ordered by key (it's important for my solution) and I want to retrieve them in that order?

Comment: Maybe this will help https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/pull/26

Comment: Pagination/endless scroll is currently not a supported feature for FirebaseUI. Unless you are willing to build it yourself, this is not really a question for Stack Overfow but more a +1 on [this Github issue](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/17)

Comment: @IrvinBridge have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62617913/load-more-items-on-scroll-from-firebase-using-firebaserecycleradapter