# RecyclerView addOnScrollListener with FirebaseRecyclerAdapter

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I'm writing a program, where I'm fetching data from Firebase Database using FirebaseRecyclerAdapter

I'm trying to implement a functionality to add 20 records on every scroll and to achieve same, I'm using:

```
mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
queryUsersData = mDatabaseReference.orderByChild("timestamp").limitToFirst(20);
```

Now, the issue is I'm getting first 20 records, but on scroll I'm not getting next 20 records, as on every scroll, I want to get next 20 records

onStart()

```
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Users, UsersViewHolder> adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Users, UsersViewHolder>(
                Users.class,
                R.layout.user_layout,
                UsersViewHolder.class,
                queryUsersData
        ) {

            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(UsersViewHolder usersViewHolder, Users users, int position) {
                 final String userID = getRef(position).getKey();
                 ....
            }
      };
      usersList.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

RecyclerView addOnScrollListener

```
Boolean isScrolling = false;
int currentItems, totalItems, scrollOutItems;

..........

usersList.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
                if(newState == AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL) {
                    isScrolling = true;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                currentItems = linearLayoutManager.getChildCount();
                totalItems = linearLayoutManager.getItemCount();
                scrollOutItems = linearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

                if(isScrolling && (currentItems + scrollOutItems == totalItems)) {
                    isScrolling = false;
                }

            }
        });
```

Now what to do next ? to achieve my goal!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firebase infinite scroll list view Load 10 items on Scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44777989/firebase-infinite-scroll-list-view-load-10-items-on-scrolling)

Answer (score 0):

Pagination will achieve want you want cleanly and reliably, I've recently used it with Kotlin, but there is a java implementation here.

[Pagination With Java + Firebase Real-Time Database](https://blog.usejournal.com/an-easy-way-to-implement-pagination-in-firebase-realtime-database-488eefc01b21)